# code splitting not working properly on vue-cli generated project

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, vue-cli, dynamic-import

I created a vue project a couple of years ago and I always "felt" that the first load was too slow. It took a while to me to realize that the whole app was being loaded at the first page, say '/'.

I tried following the instructions (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#lazy-loading-routes) but still, the first load would just load the whole app.

My project is getting bigger and I though there was a problem with its design, but after a longer time working with vuejs everything seems fine from that standpoint.

So today I decided to fix it. To do so I simplified the project as much as I could in order to replicate it. And I was able to do it.

The issue is that even though I'm using this syntax: `() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ThisShouldNotBeLoaded" */ '../components/Fail.vue')` whenever I request a route that does not require that module, the module is loaded (dev tools => inspect => network and you'll see it 'pass' through the network).

What I don't understand is if this is a vuejs problem, a design problem, a webpack problem or even something else, maybe a dependency is causing this, not sure where to look.

The good news is that I'm able to replicate it. It could be an issue but I have no idea where (webpack, vuejs, vue-cli, etc..).

If you have 5 minutes, please clone this repo and see if you understand what is going on.

Thanks!

REPO: https://github.com/nriesco/vuex-router-webpack-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979#issuecomment-373027130

When creating this project I selected the "PWA" option that somehow overrides any library lazy loading.

I tried removing the package (`npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-pwa`) but as explained in the previous link by selecting PWA upon creation the project will be configured to use prefetch.

So adding this to my `vue.config.js` file solves the issue:

```js
chainWebpack: (config) => {
  config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
}
```

The code is here: https://github.com/nriesco/vuex-router-webpack-test/blob/master/vue.config.js#L6-L8